# How do I call a function only after an async function has completed?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function `Admin` that runs asynchronously in the background.

Is there a way to make sure that the function is completed before calling the code after it?

(I am using a `flag` to check the success of the async operation. If the flag is 0, the user is not an admin and should go to the `NormalLogin()`)

```
@IBAction func LoginAction(sender: UIButton) {
  Admin()

  if(bool.flag == 0) {
    NormalLogin()
  }
}




func Admin() {
  let userName1 = UserName.text
  let userPassword = Password.text
  let findTimeLineData2:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Admins")
  findTimeLineData2.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if !(error != nil){
      for object in objects as! [PFObject] {
        let userName2 = object.objectForKey("AdminUserName") as! String
        let userPassword2 = object.objectForKey("AdminPassword") as! String

        if(userName1 == userName2 && userPassword == userPassword2) {
          //hes an admin
          bool.flag = 1

          self.performSegueWithIdentifier("AdminPage", sender: self)

          self.UserName.text = ""
          self.Password.text = ""
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to update your question with relevant code. Then point out what issue you are having with that code.

Comment: Formatting your code so that the braces line up will help people read it.

Comment: If you have lines of code that can only run after the completion of other code, then put those lines in a completion block for that other code.

Comment: You can either pass a completion block, or use a semaphore

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Now you should restore your answer after making it a bit more specific to the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into completion handlers and asynchronous programming. Here's an example of an async function that you can copy into a playground:

**defining the function**

notice the "completion" parameter is actually a function with a type of `(Bool)->()`. Meaning that the function takes a boolean and returns nothing.

```
func getBoolValue(number : Int, completion: (result: Bool)->()) {
    if number > 5 {
        // when your completion function is called you pass in your boolean
        completion(result: true)
    } else {
        completion(result: false)
    }
}
```

**calling the function**

here getBoolValue runs first, when the completion handler is called (above code) your closure is run with the result you passed in above.

```
getBoolValue(8) { (result) -> () in
    // do stuff with the result
    print(result)
}
```

**applying the concept**

You could apply this concept to your code by doing this:

```
@IBAction func LoginAction(sender: UIButton) {
    // admin() calls your code, when it hits your completion handler the 
    // closure {} runs w/ "result" being populated with either true or false
    Admin() { (result) in
        print("completion result: \(result)") //<--- add this
        if result == false {
            NormalLogin()
        } else {
            // I would recommend managing this here.
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("AdminPage", sender: self)
        }
    }
}

// in your method, you pass a `(Bool)->()` function in as a parameter 
func Admin(completion: (result: Bool)->()) {
  let userName1 = UserName.text
  let userPassword = Password.text
  let findTimeLineData2:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Admins")
  findTimeLineData2.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if !(error != nil){
      for object in objects as! [PFObject] {
        let userName2 = object.objectForKey("AdminUserName") as! String
        let userPassword2 = object.objectForKey("AdminPassword") as! String

        if(userName1 == userName2 && userPassword == userPassword2) {
          // you want to move this to your calling function
          //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("AdminPage", sender: self)

          self.UserName.text = ""
          self.Password.text = ""
          // when your completion handler is hit, your operation is complete
          // and you are returned to your calling closure
          completion(result: true) // returns true
        } else {
          completion(result: false) // returns false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, I'm not able to compile your code to test it, but I think this will work fine.

Comment: This answer seems a bit premature given the complete lack of details in the question.

Comment: Hi im sorry for the lack of details im new to this forum, your code still doesnt work it runs "normallogin" even though result=true.

Comment: @Amourr I've reviewed the code I shared and it seem right to me. I've added a few more comments to help illustrate. Let me know when you're online and I'll help you debug your code in chat.